# C# - How Get days from given month with the previous/next days to fill List

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to get a list with all days of given month plus the previous days and next day to fill a week,
and select the weekends, holidays.

I need to return a XML file with:

```
    [XmlAttribute("month")]
    [Display(Name = "Month", Description = "")]
    public int Month { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Day
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("weekday")]
    [Display(Name = "Weekday", Description = "")]
    public int Weekay { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Weekend/ Holiday Day
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("weekendday")]
    [Display(Name = "Weekendday", Description = "")]
    public int Weekendday { get; set; }
```

Just like a calendar in windows.
 I try this but only get the current days month

```
    var days = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))  // Days: 1, 2 ... 31 etc.
                     .Select(day => new CalendarItem(year, month, day))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: We're not writing the code for you. Show us your aproach and we can help you on that. Start from DateTime.Now

Comment: The `DateTime` class has a handy `DaysInMonth` method which will tell you how many days in the month base on year and month.  You can also use the `DateTime` class to figure out what day of the week the 1st of the month starts.  If the 1st is not on Sunday, it should be easy for you to determine how many days back to go.  Same for the end of the month.  Write some code to do the calculation and then if you get stuck, we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this DateTime Extension:

```
 static class DateExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetRange(this DateTime source, int days)
        {
            for (var current = 0; current < days; ++current)
            {
                yield return source.AddDays(current);
            };
        }

        public static DateTime NextDayOfWeek(this DateTime start, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
        {
            while (start.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
                start = start.AddDays(-1);

            return start;
        }
    }
```

In my Class I use this:

```
    var numberOfDays = 42;

    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1).NextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
    var dates = startDate.GetRange(numberOfDays)
        .Select(date => new CalendarDaysItem(date.Month, date.Day))
                         .ToList();
```

Define const to get number days;
Get days with start day week as monday;